# Bank Days (Working Business Days) Connected To SQL Source

Tags: sorting, date, powerbi, calendar

How do I show the working days for 2023 and 2024 in a table in Power BI?
When I try to add in the Working Days it shows up as calendar days and includes weekends and holidays.

Is there a way to show this?

As I'm researching how to accomplish this I thought I may ask this group as you all have been extremely helpful in some tricky situations!

Connected my bank days table in excel to my SQL table in Power BI via the date tables.
I'm getting the right figures for the days, but they aren't sorting chronologically...
I need them to sort chronologically.

Sorting Issue:

[image: Sorting Issue]

Date Table For Sorting:

[image: Date Table For Sorting]

Comment: I've tried creating and merging columns for unique values to sort by, and even an index to sort by. BI won't let me sort by those columns since the column I am wanting to sort is not unique. It repeats the same naming convention for each month...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by adjusting my source data.
By adding a "0" to the Day field "Day 01, Day 02" and so forth for each month across the two year period.
This allowed the Bank Days to sort chronologically. Often the simplest solutions to our problems!